# Grouping observations by a variable

Tags: sas, grouping, renaming

sorry if this is redundant w another post, but couldn't find an answer when searching.

I have a long list of medications, and several medications have multiple doses, eg:

```
Medication A 3 mg tablet
Medication A 5 mg tablet
Medication B 3 mg tablet
Medication B 5 mg tablet
```

I have been trying to write SAS code to create a third variable (newmed) which will assign a new name to each medication without the dose (eg, all Medication A doses will be called MedA, all Medication B doses will be called MedB). Here's my code:

```
data medsorted;
SET library.meds;
if DISCHARGE_MEDICATION_NAME="med1_7.5_mg_tablet" THEN newmed= "med1";
if DISCHARGE_MEDICATION_NAME="med1_6_mg_tablet" THEN newmed= "med1";

if DISCHARGE_MEDICATION_NAME="med2_100_mg/ml_subcutaneous_syringe" THEN newmed= "med2";
if DISCHARGE_MEDICATION_NAME="med2_120_mg/ml_subcutaneous_syringe" THEN newmed = "med2";    

/*etc - the list of med goes on*/

run;
```

I also tried this using "or" statements, iterating the new med name over the entire list of if statements. Either way, the program runs but the new dataset medsorted does not have any entries in the newmed column - it is blank.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Your data in the first part does not line up with what you are checking in `DISCHARGE_MEDICATION_NAME`.  Can you post the actual values in that variable?

Comment: Look into the scan function to extract the first portion of the drug name. If your drug name is more comples this won't work.

Comment: @Reeza, agree.  That's why I asked what the values actually look like.

Comment: Be aware that what you are doing is **case-sensitive** matching. If your data and code do not match in case, you'll get a completely empty new med column. Often you'll want to use `if lowcase(VAR) = 'lower case name'  then ...`.

Answer (score 0):

From the small amount of data you provided, it looks like you might be able to use the [SUBSTR](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000212267.htm) function.

```
Data medsorted;
LENGTH NEWMED $4;
SET library.meds;
NEWMED=substr(DISCHARGE_MEDICATION_NAME, 1, 4);
```

If your data is more varied than that, repost more examples